# Use dsl.Collected inside a dsl.Condition context

Tags: kubeflow-pipelines

I'm trying to use the output of `dsl.ParallelFor` downstream within a
`dsl.Condition` and I get this error: `TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: int`
I know regular output of components can be use in `dsl.Condition` contexts without issues, and `dsl.Collected`  outside the context works fine, so is there any way to get the best of both worlds and get this to work ?

```
from typing import List

from kfp import compiler, dsl
from kfp.dsl import Input, Model, Output


@dsl.component
def some_string(k: int, model: Output[Model]):
    model = "x"


@dsl.component
def always_one() -> int:
    return 1


@dsl.component
def component_with_collection(models: Input[List[Model]]) -> str:
    return ".".join([model for model in models])


@dsl.pipeline
def main_pipeline():
    always_one_task = always_one()

    with dsl.ParallelFor(items=[1, 5, 10, 25], parallelism=2) as i:
        some_string_task = some_string(k=i)

    with dsl.Condition(always_one_task.output == 1):
        component_task = component_with_collection(
            models=dsl.Collected(some_string_task.outputs["model"])
        )


compiler.Compiler().compile(main_pipeline, "main_compiled.yaml")
```